# how to handle keyboard and click event

Tags: dojo, events, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript API and I want to show a message in console's log when I hold down `"e"` and click on a graphic drawn by a user.

```
this.map.graphics.on ("click", lang.hitch(this, function(evt){ 

  if (evt.keyCode == 69 ) {

      console.log("e clicked ");

  } 

}));
```

I know that e's code is 69 but I `think evt.keyCode == 69` need some changes.

anybody can help me?

Comment: which version of Js api you're using ?

Comment: I am using arcgis js api 16 compact.

Comment: please recheck if its  arcgis js api 2 / 3 or version 4 ?

Comment: It is not version 4 (    that support 3d )  it is 16. It means that support 2d.

Comment: There is no version 16 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. Do you maybe mean 3.16?

Answer (score 1):

The `click` doesn't know about any letter key pressed. It only knows if Ctrl/Shift/Meta keys where pressed while you clicked.

For your use case, I think you would have to first listen for `key-down` and when the key pressed is `e`, then you listen for the click.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, listens for a click and keypress of 'e'

```
.click(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 69) {
        console.log("e clicked");
     }
});
```

See also related [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848002/handling-events-for-mouse-click-and-keydown-or-keypress-for-non-modifier-keys), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674456/how-to-combine-keypress-on-click-function-in-javascript)

Edit: This may be a better solution: [How to check if key is pressed during click event in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445613/how-can-i-check-if-key-is-pressed-during-click-event-with-jquery/2445635#2445635) adapted for 'e':

```
var Pressed = false;
$(window).keydown(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == 69) { // e
    Pressed = true;
  }
}).keyup(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == 69) { // e
    Pressed = false;
  }
});

yourfunction.click(function() {
  if (Pressed) {
    console.log("e clicked");
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```